# Update a table with join

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to update a table by passing value within the query. Note the value is not coming from another table. However, the key that I am using to identify the item that is common across the board is in another table. How do I join the two to make sure I update the correct records?
Database: Oracle 10g
Running the query in Toad
Please help.

This is what I have so far:

```
UPDATE HCS.ITEMINVENTORY
SET HCS.ITEMINVENTORY.BATCHGROUPING = 'ADMIXED'
WHERE (ITEMINVENTORY.FACILITYCODE = 'B')
    AND (ITEMINVENTORY.FORMULARYSTATUS = 'Y')
    AND (ITEMDISPENSESIZE.ITEMID = ITEMINVENTORY.ITEMID)"Notice the second table"
    AND (HCS.ITEMNUMBER IN (18501346,18800284)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only apply the update where it exists in ITEMDISPENSESIZE, use an EXISTS subquery. Like so:

```
UPDATE HCS.ITEMINVENTORY
SET HCS.ITEMINVENTORY.BATCHGROUPING = 'ADMIXED'
WHERE (ITEMINVENTORY.FACILITYCODE = 'B')
    AND (ITEMINVENTORY.FORMULARYSTATUS = 'Y')
    AND EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM   ITEMDISPENSESIZE
        WHERE  ITEMDISPENSESIZE.ITEMID = ITEMINVENTORY.ITEMID
        AND    ITEMDISPENSESIZE.ITEMNUMBER IN ('18501346','18800284')
    );
```

Comment: Yes, as I said HCS.ITEMNUMBER doesn't refer to anything in your UPDATE statement. What table should that refer to?

Comment: ITEMNUMBER refers to the table itemdispensesize. Thats the only key that will update the item I want to update and it resides in that second table itemdispensesize.

Comment: OK, then that clause should be part of the EXISTS. I've edited my answer.

Comment: That may be because ITEMNUMBER is not a number field. I've put quotes around it if that's the case. Did you check this?

Comment: Thats exactly what it is! Now I only have to put quotes around ~700 of those items! Any quick suggestions?

Comment: Load the ITEMNUMBER values into a table, and join to that in the EXISTS subquery.

Comment: Thank you for your help! You save my evening!

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
update Table
   set column1 = 'new value'
   from table1 a, table2 b
   where a.column2 = x 
   and a.column3 = y
   and b.column4 = z
```